# calling function from another view controller to update specific cell

Tags: ios, swift

in my SecondViewClass, I'm trying to update cell 0 in ViewController class whenever the button is clicked by calling @objc func toReload() in ViewController.

SecondViewController codes:

```
@IBAction func setFav(_ sender: Any) 
{

let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "toVC", bundle: nil)

let VC: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "toVC") as! ViewController

   VC.toReload(rowNumber: 0)

}

ViewController codes:


@objc func toReload(rowNumber: Int){
    reload = true

let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowNumber, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

whenever I click on the button it gave me a thread error

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new vc other than the real presented one

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "toVC", bundle: nil)
let VC: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "toVC") as! ViewController
```

and this access the table when this fake vc isn't yet loaded resulting in a nil exception

```
VC.toReload(rowNumber: 0)
```

you need a delegate var

```
weak var delegate:FirstVC?
```

when you present SecondVc set it like

```
let second = //
second.delegate = self
present/push(second
```

then use this inside `setFav`

```
delegate?.toReload(rowNumber: 0)
```

Comment: i tried it and it works to call the function but it gave me an error in this line : tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none). it said the optional value is nil and I think that means the tableview. how to reload the tableview before update the new cell. @Sh_Khan

Comment: @user9413533 use **tableView.reloadData()**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this on delegates as mentioned by @Sh_Khan or also with closer easily.

In your SecondVC create

```
var completion:((_ index:Int)->())?
```

call this completion inside `setFav` like

```
guard let completionCall = completion else {return}
completionCall(0)
```

In your firstVC where you created SecondVC instance do this with same instance

```
secondVCObj = { index in 
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowNumber, section: 0)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
  }
```